# WinRT - How to get line and column at cursor from a TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How do I get line and column at cursor from a text box in my Windows 8 Metro App? There is no GetFirstCharIndexFromLine method like there was in WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
// Returns a one-based line number and column of the selection start
private static Tuple<int, int> GetPosition(TextBox text)
{
    // Selection start always reports the position as though newlines are one character
    string contents = text.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");

    int i, pos = 0, line = 1;
    // Loop through all the lines up to the selection start
    while ((i = contents.IndexOf('\n', pos, text.SelectionStart - pos)) != -1)
    {
        pos = i + 1;
        line++;
    }

    // Column is the remaining characters
    int column = text.SelectionStart - pos + 1;

    return Tuple.Create(line, column);
}
```

This will get the line and column numbers.

Comment: Good, but it does not take line wrapping into account and performs unnecessary replacements (string copying).

Comment: Note you could use GetRectFromCharacterIndex to go through the characters and see where they end up on screen.